# Swapping paragraphs temporarily

Tags: javascript, css

I have this paragraph tag I shake violently and rip from the screen which works fine except I'd love to have it be temporarily replaced with another paragraph until it comes back.

```css
    #poltergeist {
     -webkit-animation: fling 30s;
     animation: fling 30s;
     animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes fling {
     20% {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
     20.1% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-1deg);}
     20.2% {-webkit-transform:rotate(2deg);}
     20.3% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-2deg);}
     20.4% {-webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);}
     20.5% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);}
     20.6% {-webkit-transform:rotate(4deg);}
     20.7% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-4deg);}
     20.8% {-webkit-transform:rotate(5deg);}
     20.9% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-5deg);}
     21.0% {-webkit-transform:rotate(4deg);}
     21.1% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-4deg);}
     21.2% {-webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);}
     21.3% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);}
     21.4% {-webkit-transform:rotate(2deg);}
     21.5% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-2deg);}
     21.7% {-webkit-transform:rotate(4deg);}
     21.9% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-4deg);}
     22.1% {-webkit-transform:rotate(8deg);}
     22.3% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-8deg);}
     22.5% {-webkit-transform:rotate(20deg);}
     22.7% {-webkit-transform:translate(100px,100px);}
     23% {-webkit-transform:translate(-2000px,-200px);}
     24% {opacity:1;filter:(alpha(opacity=100));}
     25% {opacity:0;filter:(alpha(opacity=0));}
     89%{-webkit-transform:translate(0px,0px);}
     90% {opacity:0;filter:(alpha(opacity=0));}
     100% {opacity:1;filter:(alpha(opacity=100));}
    }
    
    @keyframes fling {
     20% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
     20.1% {transform:rotate(-1deg);}
     20.2% {transform:rotate(2deg);}
     20.3% {transform:rotate(-2deg);}
     20.4% {transform:rotate(3deg);}
     20.5% {transform:rotate(-3deg);}
     20.6% {transform:rotate(4deg);}
     20.7% {transform:rotate(-4deg);}
     20.8% {transform:rotate(5deg);}
     20.9% {transform:rotate(-5deg);}
     21.0% {transform:rotate(4deg);}
     21.1% {transform:rotate(-4deg);}
     21.2% {transform:rotate(3deg);}
     21.3% {transform:rotate(-3deg);}
     21.4% {transform:rotate(2deg);}
     21.5% {transform:rotate(-2deg);}
     21.7% {transform:rotate(4deg);}
     21.9% {transform:rotate(-4deg);}
     22.1% {transform:rotate(8deg);}
     22.3% {transform:rotate(-8deg);}
     22.5% {transform:rotate(20deg);}
     22.7% {transform:translate(100px,100px);}
     23% {transform:translate(-2000px,-200px);}
     24% {opacity:1;filter:(alpha(opacity=100));}
     25% {opacity:0;filter:(alpha(opacity=0));}
     89%{transform:translate(0px,0px);}
     90% {opacity:0;filter:(alpha(opacity=0));}
     100% {opacity:1;filter:(alpha(opacity=100));}
    }
```

```html
<p id="poltergeist">Sample text</p>
```

Comment: Please describe the desired behaviour in more details: what do you mean by "replaced with"? What do you mean by "temporarily"?

Comment: Well I am working on a site for a haunted house. Id like the new paragragh to just fade in/out, stay for the duration of time the space is now empty.

Comment: Well the first thing you'd have to do is make the paragraphs the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 2**
here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RGbONN)

I Removed Javascript, now it's pure css 
based on your code, i added these lines

```
div.cont p { position:absolute;}
div.cont p#poltergeist { z-index: 2;} 
div.cont p#replaced { z-index: 1; }
```

and here is your complete page

```
<html><head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script></head><body>

<style>
html{
  font-family:'Josefin Slab',sans;
}

body{
background:rgb(5,5,5) url(http://thelab.org.au/online/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/landscape.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
color:rgb(88,114,103);
}

p{
font-size:160%;
margin:5% 3%;
padding:1%;
border-color:rgba(248,255,157,0.3);
border-width:6px;
border-style:groove;
background-color:rgb(5,5,5);

}

.credit{
    text-align:right;
    font-size:80%;
    line-height:200%;
    font-style:italic;
    -o-transition: all 3s;
    -moz-transition: all 3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 3s;
    transition: all 3s;

}

.credit:hover{
    font-size:200%;
    line-height:100%;
}

.credit a{
  color:inherit;
  text-decoration:none;
}


#eyecanvas{
background: url(http://thelab.org.au/online/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/cat_eyes.jpg);
background-size:100% 100%;
}

.ghost{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    opacity: 0.2;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    z-index:1;
    -o-transition: opacity 5s;filter 5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 5s;filter 5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 5s;filter 5s;
    transition: opacity 5s;filter 5s;
    -webkit-animation: hauntx 21s infinite, haunty 37s infinite, fadeout 29s infinite, moveback 15s infinite; 
    animation:  hauntx 21s infinite, haunty 37s infinite, fadeout 29s infinite, moveback 15s infinite; 

}

.ghost:hover{
    opacity:1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

@-webkit-keyframes hauntx {
    0% {right: 5%;}
    50% {right: 80%;}
    100% {right: 5%;}
 }

 @keyframes hauntx {
    0% {right: 5%;}
    50% {right: 80%;}
    100% {right: 5%;}
 }

@-webkit-keyframes haunty {
    0% {bottom: 5%;}
    30% {bottom: 80%;}
    100% {bottom: 5%;}
 }

 @keyframes haunty {
    0% {bottom: 5%;}
    30% {bottom: 80%;}
    100% {bottom: 5%;}
 }

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout{
    20% {filter:blur(0px);-webkit-filter:blur(0px);}
    30% {filter:blur(50px);-webkit-filter:blur(50px);}
    60% {filter:blur(0px);-webkit-filter:blur(0px);}

}

@keyframes fadeout{
    20% {filter:blur(0px);-webkit-filter:blur(0px);}
    30% {filter:blur(50px);-webkit-filter:blur(50px);}
    60% {filter:blur(0px);-webkit-filter:blur(0px);}

}

@-webkit-keyframes moveback{
    30% {z-index:-1;}
    60% {z-index:1;}

}

@keyframes moveback{
    30% {z-index:-1;}
    60% {z-index:1;}

}
/* code added by me */
  div.cont p { position:absolute;}
div.cont p#poltergeist { z-index: 2;} 
div.cont p#replaced { z-index: 1; } 
/* end  */

#poltergeist{
    -webkit-animation: fling 30s;
    animation: fling 30s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fling {
   20% {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
    20.1% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-1deg);}
    20.2% {-webkit-transform:rotate(2deg);}
    20.3% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-2deg);}
    20.4% {-webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);}
    20.5% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);}
    20.6% {-webkit-transform:rotate(4deg);}
    20.7% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-4deg);}
    20.8% {-webkit-transform:rotate(5deg);}
    20.9% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-5deg);}
    21.0% {-webkit-transform:rotate(4deg);}
    21.1% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-4deg);}
    21.2% {-webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);}
    21.3% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);}
    21.4% {-webkit-transform:rotate(2deg);}
    21.5% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-2deg);}
    21.7% {-webkit-transform:rotate(4deg);}
    21.9% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-4deg);}
    22.1% {-webkit-transform:rotate(8deg);}
    22.3% {-webkit-transform:rotate(-8deg);}
    22.5% {-webkit-transform:rotate(20deg);}
    22.7% {-webkit-transform:translate(100px,100px);}
    23% {-webkit-transform:translate(-2000px,-200px);}
    24% {opacity:1;filter:(alpha(opacity=100));}
    25% {opacity:0;filter:(alpha(opacity=0));}
    89%{-webkit-transform:translate(0px,0px);}
    90% {opacity:0;filter:(alpha(opacity=0));}
    100% {opacity:1;filter:(alpha(opacity=100));}}

@keyframes fling{
    20% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    20.1% {transform:rotate(-1deg);}
    20.2% {transform:rotate(2deg);}
    20.3% {transform:rotate(-2deg);}
    20.4% {transform:rotate(3deg);}
    20.5% {transform:rotate(-3deg);}
    20.6% {transform:rotate(4deg);}
    20.7% {transform:rotate(-4deg);}
    20.8% {transform:rotate(5deg);}
    20.9% {transform:rotate(-5deg);}
    21.0% {transform:rotate(4deg);}
    21.1% {transform:rotate(-4deg);}
    21.2% {transform:rotate(3deg);}
    21.3% {transform:rotate(-3deg);}
    21.4% {transform:rotate(2deg);}
    21.5% {transform:rotate(-2deg);}
    21.7% {transform:rotate(4deg);}
    21.9% {transform:rotate(-4deg);}
    22.1% {transform:rotate(8deg);}
    22.3% {transform:rotate(-8deg);}
    22.5% {transform:rotate(20deg);}
    22.7% {transform:translate(100px,100px);}
    23% {transform:translate(-2000px,-200px);}
    24% {opacity:1;filter:(alpha(opacity=100));}
    25% {opacity:0;filter:(alpha(opacity=0));}
    89%{transform:translate(0px,0px);}
    90% {opacity:0;filter:(alpha(opacity=0));}
    100% {opacity:1;filter:(alpha(opacity=100));}
}
    div.cont{height:150px;width:600px}
</style>

    <h1>About the mansion</h1>
<div class=cont>
    <p id="poltergeist">The house is full of ghosts and other spirits who do not want visitors.</p>
<p id="replaced">The house is full of puppies kittens and rainbows who love visitors.</p>
</div>

<p id="eyecanvas">
The first edition was substantially a transcript of some lectures
which I delivered in the year 1888 with the object of giving a sketch of
the history, previous to the nineteenth century, that should be intelligible
to any one acquainted with the elements of mathematics. In the
second edition, issued in 1893, I rearranged parts of it, and introduced
a good deal of additional matter.
</p>
<p>
The scheme of arrangement will be gathered from the table of contents
at the end of this preface. Shortly it is as follows. The first chapter
contains a brief statement of what is known concerning the mathematics
of the Egyptians and Phoenicians; this is introductory to the history
of mathematics under Greek influence. The subsequent history is divided
into three periods: first, that under Greek influence, chapters ii
to vii; second, that of the middle ages and renaissance, chapters viii
to xiii; and lastly that of modern times, chapters xiv to xix.
</p>
<p>
In discussing the mathematics of these periods I have confined myself
to giving the leading events in the history, and frequently have
passed in silence over men or works whose influence was comparatively
unimportant. Doubtless an exaggerated view of the discoveries of those
mathematicians who are mentioned may be caused by the non-allusion
to minor writers who preceded and prepared the way for them, but in
all historical sketches this is to some extent inevitable, and I have done
my best to guard against it by interpolating remarks on the progress
of the science at different times. Perhaps also I should here state that
generally I have not referred to the results obtained by practical astronomers
and physicists unless there was some mathematical interest
in them. In quoting results I have commonly made use of modern notation;
the reader must therefore recollect that, while the matter is
the same as that of any writer to whom allusion is made, his proof is
sometimes translated into a more convenient and familiar language.
</p>
<p>
The greater part of my account is a compilation from existing histories
or memoirs, as indeed must be necessarily the case where the works
discussed are so numerous and cover so much ground. When authorities
disagree I have generally stated only that view which seems to me
to be the most probable; but if the question be one of importance, I
believe that I have always indicated that there is a difference of opinion
about it.
</p>
<p>
I think that it is undesirable to overload a popular account with
a mass of detailed references or the authority for every particular fact
mentioned. For the history previous to 1758, I need only refer, once for
all, to the closely printed pages of M. Cantor’s monumental Vorlesungen
&uuml;ber die Geschichte der Mathematik (hereafter alluded to as Cantor),
which may be regarded as the standard treatise on the subject, but
usually I have given references to the other leading authorities on which
</p>
<p>
I have relied or with which I am acquainted. My account for the period
subsequent to 1758 is generally based on the memoirs or monographs
referred to in the footnotes, but the main facts to 1799 have been also
enumerated in a supplementary volume issued by Prof. Cantor last year.
I hope that my footnotes will supply the means of studying in detail
the history of mathematics at any specified period should the reader
desire to do so.
</p>
<p>
My thanks are due to various friends and correspondents who have
called my attention to points in the previous editions. I shall be grateful
for notices of additions or corrections which may occur to any of my
readers.
</p>
<img class="ghost" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/ghostgirl.gif" alt="ghostgirl" height="550px"/>
<div class="credit">Background by <a href="https://www.flickr.com/people/79899037@N04">Tobiasvde</a> from <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Creepy_landscape_(8023951031).jpg">Wikimedia commons</a></div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: That isn't doing anything for me yet, will it matter that I'm running it within a custom template page on a wordpress site?

Comment: is jQuery enabled ?

Comment: it is, using <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Perhaps, you should create a jsFiddle so that @Redtail tries it there first and on his local machine/remote server next

Comment: EDIT: i added a fiddle

Comment: It's perfect, I just have to figure out what I'm doing wrong implementing it. Thank you! except.. it stops replacing the original text after the first time.

Comment: it produces once, if you like it to reporoduce you can add a `settimeout` event

Comment: Could you show me how that should look in the fiddle you created? That's the last thing then I'll leave you be, thanks.

Comment: you're the best, keep going

Comment: I will post the live page shortly to show you but I am getting an odd glitch where the two paragraphs are not taking up the same space... the replace paragraph is about 3 lines lower than where the original was... then when the original come back it goes back where it was... so the page jumps between the transition...

Comment: The code is doing what you designed it to do except the two paragraphs are not inhabiting the same spot on the page. the fade in replace paragraph comes in below the original.. pushing other content down the page. When the original comes back It goes where it was originally and the page content below it comes back up to where everything was....

Comment: try adding `width` and `height` to the `div.cont` => `div.cont{height:150px;width:200px}`

Comment: I add div.cont{height:150px;width:200px} to the javascript?

Comment: http://codepen.io/redtailmedia/pen/vXBPWP that's with the bit of css you just gave me.